# Study of Divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose we define a series as;
$$ S = a(1 + r_2 + r_2r_3 + r_2r_3r_4 ...) $$
and we define
$$ r_n = f(n) $$ such that each $ r_n <1$ but $r_{n+1}>r_n$
Is there a limit, an upper bound, or condition on $ \frac{df}{dn}$ so that the sum $S$ exists?
Also, clearly, for $r_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$, the sum doesn't exist (it diverges), hence, can we say that for all functions such that $\frac{df}{dn} >1/n^2$ will have a divergent sum?